# How to use AST eclipse parser to parse all the source files of a project?

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I am trying to use the eclipse java parser (JDT) to retrieve the AST of my program. I can parse a class and modified it. But my question is: how can I parse the entire source?

```
public static List<File> listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories(String directoryName) {

    File directory = new File(directoryName);

    //get all the files from a directory
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();

    for (File file : fList) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            listOfFiles.add(file);
            //System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }

    }

    return listOfFiles;

}
```

I have used the list to create a for in which I would parse each file, however it parse only on the last iteration.

```
parser.setSource(FileUtils.readFileToString(file).toCharArray());
```

I am sure that there is a more intelligent way to explore a project, but I did not found anything about, moreover the code I have written does not work.

Comment: See https://www.programcreek.com/2011/01/best-java-development-tooling-jdt-and-astparser-tutorials/

Comment: Note that specifically ASTParser.createASTs() (plural) methods should be preferred when parsing several related files - in particular when binding resolution is requested.